# How to use Presto with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, presto

Has anyone tried to connect power BI tool with Presto?

I have used the connectors and driver available on the [Qubole documentation](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/connectivity-options/partner-integration/powerbi-integration/powerbi-setup-connector.html) site. I have installed the drivers and connectors but it is throwing error on accessing S3 location.

Comment: Have you seen Starburst Presto PowerBI integration? Please visit: https://www.starburstdata.com/technical-blog/starburst-presto-323e-release/ and https://youtu.be/uBT7ewKDfhA?t=1294

Comment: Could you please share the connection string or connection screenshot, also the s3 error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Qubole drivers and connector will work only with [Qubole's Managed Presto Service](https://www.qubole.com/developers/presto-on-qubole/).

Disclaimer: I work for Qubole.

Comment: Remember folks, the question asks for "using powerBi with Qubole drivers" and the answer provides a solution to it. The user is not plugging their service.